# Xamarin MvvmCross Breadcrum menu

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to figure out how to create my own breadcrum menu in Xamarin using MvvmCross in an Android project. I am fairly new to Xamarin so I am not sure how to accomplish this just yet. Is it possible to include two ViewModels in the same MvxActivity and have them communicate. Is this the best way to approach this? If so how would this sample look like? How is the presentation done and the sliding animation?

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I have looked at some sample projects but they aren't making much sense especially since they are not Android based.

Thanks

Comment: What does a breadcrum menu means? If you are looking for a good sidemenu example this should do it: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: Yeah side menu, thank you I will look into this implementation today.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good MvvmCross Sidemenu example available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

You can find all elements you require such as presentation and sliding animation there.